# How to update this to auto populate the date in an input field

Tags: html, date, auto-populate

Haven't posted anything in a while so apologies if I am missing something.
I am trying to update these signature forms that were grandfathered down to me. I have very little experience with HTML.
When I copy and paste it into a different section its not showing up how it previously has.
To be honest I have no idea where the variables came from and neither does my manager.

`<label>DATE </label> <input ztype="date" class="form-control small-ip200" id="datemulticlient3" name="datemulticlient3" placeholder="Date" label="Signature Date" value="[AppointmentDate]" />`

I have tried different ways to just start over the code from those other coding sites but I am unable to figure it out. I appreciate any help!

Comment: I looked a little more into it, it looks like its working but the icon and input field are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const d = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-US');
            document.getElementById("datemulticlient3").value = d;
        });
    </script>
```

this will change the value when the page loads using the current date object, then converting it to the short format. W3Schools is a good resource for getting started with date objects: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp